# Compatible struct types

Tags: c, types, language-lawyer

The C 11 standard defines struct compatibility as follows (6.2.7):

> Moreover, two  structure, union, or  enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following  requirements:  If  one  is  declared  with  a  tag,  the other  shall  be  declared  with  the  same  tag.  If  both  are  completed  anywhere  within  their respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be   a   one-to-one   correspondence   between   their   members   such   that   each   pair   of corresponding members are declared with compatible types…

That means I can have 2 files like this:

foo.c:

```
struct struc {
    int x;
};

int foo(struct struc *s)
{
    return s->x;
}
```

main.c:

```
struct struc {
    float x;
};

int foo(struct struc *s);

int main(void)
{
    return foo(&(struct struc){1.2f});
}
```

Smells like undefined behavior (as it is for types like int and float). But if I am understanding the standard correctly (maybe I am misinterpreting the second sentence), this is allowed. If so, what is the rationale behind this? Why not also specify that structs in separate translation units must also be structurally equivalent?

Comment: `int` and `float` are not "compatible types" as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: It does specify they they be structurally equivalent ("corresponding members are declared with compatible types") -- and also that the member names be the same (it speaks about the names in the missing rest of the last sentence).

Comment: @PSkocik But doesn't it say the structural equivalence applies only if they are both completed in the same translation unit?

Comment: @WingerSendon "if both are completed within their irrespective translation units". Your `struct struc` in foo.c is completed (==isn't just a forward declaration) and your `struct struc` in main.c is completed: both `struct struc` are completed within their irrespective translation units.

Comment: Oh. Got confused there. Why even mention "irrespective translation units" there at all? Could of just said "if they are completed"...

Comment: The standard says “respective”, not “irrespective”. When quoting other people (or committees or documents), please be careful to quote **exactly** (or to indicate omissions with “…” or rewordings/explanations with brackets).

Comment: @EricPostpischil looks like it messed up the space characters when I copied. It got changed from "their respective" to "the irrespective" for some reason..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Smells like undefined behavior

Because it is.

---

> But if I am understanding the standard correctly

This doesn't seem to be the case in this particular instance.

> this is allowed.

Nope. I do not see (and you do not explain) how the standard language could be interpreted this way.

The standard says

> *If both are completed anywhere within their respective translation units*

This condition holds in your your example.

> *then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types*

This requirement is not satisfied, so the types are not compatible.

---

> Why not also specify that structs in separate translation units must also be structurally equivalent?

The standard specifies exactly that. "[o]ne-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types" is precisely the definition of structural equivalence.

Comment: why won't you just say `float` is not compatible with `int`? or at least add it somewhere in your answer, I get the language-layer answers but those type of answers just not helpful

Comment: @user2162550 OP obviously understands that int and float are not compatible. The question is about the language that presumably makes the two struct compatible despite that.