# Can the second and third operands of conditional operator have incomplete object types?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, incomplete-type

Per C11 (as well as per C2x) I understand that the second and third operands of conditional operator can have incomplete object types. Is that correct?

Code:

```
struct x y;
void f(void) { 1 ? y : y; }
```

Invocations:

```
$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t0.c:2:24: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t0.c: In function 'f':
t0.c:2:20: error: 'y' has an incomplete type 'struct x'
    2 | void f(void) { 1 ? y : y; }
      |                    ^
t0.c:2:24: error: 'y' has an incomplete type 'struct x'
    2 | void f(void) { 1 ? y : y; }

$ cl t0.c /std:c11
t0.c(1): error C2079: 'y' uses undefined struct 'x'

$ icc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t0.c(2): error: incomplete type is not allowed
  void f(void) { 1 ? y : y; }
                     ^
t0.c(2): error: incomplete type is not allowed
  void f(void) { 1 ? y : y; }
                         ^
```

Comment: `?:` operator takes **values** of one of operands. The incomplete type cannot have value.

Comment: I have not found a constraint for this yet, but C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, which specifies lvalue conversion, says “… If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined…”

Comment: By the way, particularly since you are doing formal analysis of the C standard, “Can…” is the wrong question to ask. The C standard does not impose any restrictions on what a programmer may write. You can write code where the operands do not have complete types. The C standard only specifies the interpretation of programs written in C. You can ask whether C defines the behavior when you do this, such as the behavior of the program or the behavior of whether the C implementation must issue a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Clang 11.0.0 accepts this code without complaint, with `-c -Wmost -Werror -std=c18 -pedantic`:

```
extern struct x y;
void f(void) { (void) (1 ? y : y); }
```

This is curious because the type of `y` is incomplete when `f` is being analyzed, so it implies the compiler analyzes the code sufficiently to determine the result of the conditional operator is not used and so the incompleteness of its operands is irrelevant.

In any case, C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue conversion*… If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined.

This is not in a constraints paragraph, so a C implementation is not required to diagnose it.

However, the rule is puzzling. Lvalue conversion nominally occurs during program execution, since it needs the values stored in the bytes of an object. However, whether a type is complete or incomplete is a translation-time property; C 2018 6.2.5 1 says “… At various points within a translation unit an object type may be *incomplete* (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or *complete* (having sufficient information).” If `struct x { int i; }` appeared after `f`, would the operands of the conditional operator be complete (because the type was completed before execution and hence before lvalue conversion occurred) or incomplete (because the type was incomplete when `f` was analyzed)?

In any case, given that the operand type is incomplete, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. A compiler is free to compile it or to reject it. (Since the behavior is not defined, if the compiler does compile it, it is allowed to compile it into any code.)

Comment: 1) In [N1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (draft) in 6.3.2.1 2 `_Alignof` is in the list. Why was it removed? 2) Does it follow that the unary `&` operator is the only one operator that allows operand of incomplete object type?

Comment: @pmor: `_Alignof` was removed from there because it can only be applied to a type, not an expression. It was a mistake to have it in 6.3.2.1 2. My guess is an earlier draft allowed applying it to an expression, and that was later removed but 6.3.2.1 2 was not updated before publication.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got that idea from. Like the compiler is telling you: no, you can't use incomplete types because C doesn't even allow you to use an object of incomplete type in any expression and that's not related to the `?:` operator as such.

What you can do with the `?:` operator however, is to use *pointers* to (qualified) objects of incomplete type. As long as the objects are compatible, then that is fine.

```
// strictly conforming C program
struct x* y;
struct x* z;
void f(void) { 1 ? y : z; }
```

For this to make sense, `struct x` must be defined *somewhere* though. But not necessarily in the same translation unit.

Comment: Re: "where you got that idea from": for Conditional operator there is no constraint "both operands shall not have incomplete object types". Re: "C doesn't even allow you to use an object of incomplete type in any expression": where it says so? Consider: `struct x y; void* p = &y; struct x {int i;};`. Here the operand of the unary `&` operator is lvalue that designates an object of incomplete type.

Comment: @pmor There is no constraint saying that they may have incomplete type either. Maybe I should have said any expression subject to lvalue conversion, in which case it is implicitly covered by the lvalue conversion rules that specify "If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Consider Constraints for Additive operators. There it is required that "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible _complete object types_". The absence of requirement on (in)complete object types in Constraints for Conditional operator implies that incomplete object types are allowed. Hence, Clang does not complain (about constraint viol.). P.S. There is no (?) requirement for Library functions to _not_ do any operations outside of the Description section. Hence, `acos` checking email on top of computing the principal value of the arc cosine is conforming.

Comment: Note: The same "if no requirement, then not xxx" interpretation is in the comments [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73571530/1778275): "If no rule says it, then those types are not compatible."

Comment: @pmor The absence of something in ISO C rather means that the behavior is undefined. For example C specifies conversion from "pointer to type" to "qualified pointer to type" but doesn't mention what will happen when you do the other way around. Thus _undefined_, not well-defined.