# Is the unary & operator the only one operator that allows operand of incomplete object type w/o triggering undefined behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, incomplete-type

A simple question: is the unary `&` operator the only one operator that allows operand of incomplete object type w/o triggering undefined behavior?

---

UPD. Reason of the question: I was reading [Sun Studio 12: C User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjals/index.html):

> Most expression operators require complete object types. The only three exceptions are the unary & operator, the first operand of the comma operator, and the second and third operands of the ?: operator.

The `?:` operator being used with the second and third operands of incomplete types [leads to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876126/1778275). This is due to lvalue conversion. The same for the comma operator. By analyzing exceptions of lvalue conversion (C11, 6.3.2.1p2) I've concluded that the unary `&` operator is the only one operator that allows operand of incomplete object type w/o triggering undefined behavior. However, I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: No, the parentheses operator allows it too. And `_Generic`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, but I'm specifically interested in operators. Btw, why `_Generic` is "Generic selection" rather than "Generic operator"?

Comment: *The ?: operator being used with the second and third operands of incomplete types leads to undefined behavior.*  A compiler is free to define that behavior.

Comment: `(void)(void)0` is legal (C11 6.3.2.2) and is applying operator `(void)` to an operand with incomplete type `(void)0`.

Comment: @IanAbbott OK. Does it mean that there are only _two_ operators that allow operand of incomplete object type w/o triggering undefined behavior?

Comment: The two operators fall into different classes. You can void a void expression but cannot take its address. You can take the address of a non-void incomplete lvalue but cannot void it.